# Как получить атрибут for тега label в шаблоне Django?

Tags: python, django

Если я хочу отрисовать форму вручную, как мне получить атрибут for?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="???">{{form.username.label}}</label>
  {{form.username}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем? не проце вывести `form.username` ?

---

**update:**

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
```

Источник: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: for - это атрибут id тега input (не name).  А не отрисовываю через обычное {{form.username}}, потому что это с бутстраповскими классами поженить не получается.